# Car wont reverse

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

So I already have a car in the Blender game engine. It drives fine (suspension brakes etc.) However, for some reason it doesn't drive in reverse. If I press the down key quickly, it moves back a bit and just rolls, but it doesn't have constant acceleration backwards. If needed, I have uploaded the [code](https://pastebin.com/7pQQ3f0r) and the .blend file.

I think that it is to do with the brake being activated when the reverse key is pressed as the reverse key is used as a brake and to reverse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be that you use braking as long as the velocity is higher than a positive treshold. If slower, then braking is deactivated and only reverse acceleration by the engine is applied. The same thing would happen when you drive backwards and want to accelerate forward.

You need a logic when the car brakes and when it accelerates towards the opposite direction. Unfortunately, I can not give you example code because I don't know this data structure and how to access the cars velocity.